# workbox serviceworker working everywhere except Chrome: Uncaught (in promise) DOMException

Tags: javascript, webpack, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

Workbox is not working on Chrome, but it works everywhere else, 
which is ironic since I believe this is a Google library, 
the error that shows is :

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException : sw.js line 1
```

Chrome:

[image]

Opera
[image]

Firefox
[image]

I'm using the workbox-webpack-plugin

webpack.config.js

```
    const workbox = require('workbox-webpack-plugin'); 

    module.exports = {
        plugins: [
            new workbox.GenerateSW({
                swDest: './service-worker.js',
                skipWaiting: true,
                clientsClaim: true
            })
        ]  
 }
```

index.ts (entry)

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/js/app/dist/service-worker.js');
  }); 
}
```

EDIT: This is the line of code that throws the error

[image]

[image]

EDIT 2:
it actually works on icognito mode, removing browser data still doesn't help.

[image]

EDIT 3:
Updating to the newest beta 1, is even worse, since aside from the last errors it will show another one, however, this version works in Chrome's icognito mode and other browsers too.

[image]

Comment: Hi, did u ever figure this out? I'm getting the exact same errors, works in other browsers & incognito.. tried deleting all cache/history nothing works... any suggestions?

Comment: never mind, got it working... In the 'clear cache' window in chrome went over to the advanced tab, hit every checkbox, did it for all time, and no more error.. strange!

Comment: Chrome updated itself, now its fixed for me and all coworkers, I have Chrome 72 now

Answer (score 5):

This error is usually thrown if the browser is out of allocated disk space quota. 
Your incognito is working because it will be allocated with new disk quota, where as normal tabs share same disk quota.

Can you open `Application` tab in devtools and click on `Clear storage > Clear site data`? This should fix this issue in most of the cases.

[image: Disk Quota]

Comment: +1 Probably there is not enough free space on hard drive. In this case your browser may not be able to reserve some space for the cache.

Comment: What you mean is "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Quota exceeded", this is not case in this issue. As stated in the Edit 2: I had already tried to erase the data with no success. Gold help me at this point

Comment: Dang it I only read the first answer and this was here all along... What a pain in the ass this was I had no space in my hard drive! Strange it worked in Firefox...

Comment: I deleted my `Service Worker` directory in the chrome config folder on my file system and it solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome autoupdated to version 72 and now it works for me and my colleagues.
Its most probably a fixed bug.

Comment: I am using Chrome 72 and 4.0.0-beta.1/workbox-sw.js and still the same problem (upon refreshing the page twice or three times).

Answer (score 0):

You might have the scope of your SW file wrong. Try this:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/js/app/dist/service-worker.js', { scope: '/' });
  }); 
}
```

If you can not move the SW file you need to add a special header to your backend:

```
Server {

    listen www.example.com:443 ssl;

    ...

    location /js/app/dist/service-worker.js {
        add_header 'Service-Worker-Allowed' '/';
    }
}
```

(nginx configuration)

Comment: the scope / throws an exception, the same snippet with the scope "js/app/dist" works, but shows all of the exceptions above.

Comment: What's the error that has been thrown using `scope`?

Comment: The path of the provided scope ('/') is not under the max scope allowed ('/js/app/dist/'). Adjust the scope, move the Service Worker script, or use the Service-Worker-Allowed HTTP header to allow the scope.

Comment: From MDN: The service worker will only catch requests from clients under the service worker's scope.

The max scope for a service worker is the location of the worker. You can additionally add a header form your backend 

So it seems like your SW is not in the root of your app.

Comment: js/app/dist is the correct scope, its where webpack generates the file, however I just tried moving it to the / scope, it worked, but didn't fix the errors, icognito still works as I said.

Comment: I wonder then if there's some extension in your chrome that screws the SW. Any way you can test in Browserstack or another laptop? Can't think of something else. Maybe other users here will be able to help!

Comment: I've just disabled all the extensions, but got the same results, also tried it on my coworkers computer with the same results :/

Comment: the weird part is, it also works for him in icognito mode